# Simple Postman response time test

Tags: api, testing, postman

I am new to the testing APIs via Postman app and I am trying to create a simple if/else function. But whenever I run the test to force the code to console.log second msg, it fails and does not log the message..

**The code is:**

```
pm.test("Response time is less than limit", function() {
var limit = 10;

pm.expect(pm.response.responseTime).to.be.below(limit);  

if (pm.response.responseTime < limit) {      
    console.log("Response Time: " + pm.response.responseTime + " ms" + " / Response Date: " + pm.response.headers.get("Date"));
} else {
    console.log("Response time was longer than " + limit + " ms.");
}
});
```

I have found the solution of putting the pm.expect... piece of code into the first if, but I am not sure if that is the correct way. Could anybody help me with that, please?

```
pm.test("Response time is less than limit", function() {
var limit = 10;

if (pm.response.responseTime < limit) {      
    pm.expect(pm.response.responseTime).to.be.below(limit);  
    console.log("Response Time: " + pm.response.responseTime + " ms" + " / Response Date: " + pm.response.headers.get("Date"));
} else {
    console.log("Response time was longer than " + limit + " ms.");
}
});
```

API URL can be:
http://api.chucknorris.io/

Thank you!

Comment: also, is there any Slack postman group where I could ask such dummy questions? I could not find any..

Comment: https://community.postman.com is the place for those questions 

Comment: Thank you :-) I have found this as well but I thought there is sth like Slack.. :D

Comment: There used to be but we shifted things over to the community site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pm.test("Response time is less than .00000000000000000ms", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.responseTime).to.be.below(1,`Response Time:  ${pm.response.responseTime} ms Response Date ${pm.response.headers.get("Date")}`);
});
```

You can print the error message in the expect as the second argument. You can also use string literal instead of using plus sign to concatenate

[image]